# What is the best way to display an animated icon in a QTableView?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

I've been struggling with this for some times now, and I can't seem to find the right way to do this.

What I would like is the ability to use an animated icon as a decoration for some of my items (typically to show that some processing is occuring for this particular item). I have a custom table model, that I display in a `QTableView`.

My first idea was to create a custom delegate that would take care of displaying the animation. When passed a `QMovie` for the decoration role, the delegate would connect to the `QMovie` in order to update the display every time a new frame is available (see code below). However, the painter does not seem to remain valid after the call to the delegate's `paint` method (I get an error when calling the painter's `save` method, probably because the pointer no longer points to valid memory).

Another solution would be to emit the `dataChanged` signal of the item every time a new frame is available, but 1) that would induce many unnecessary overhead, since the data is not really changed; 2) it does not seem really clean to handle the movie at the model level: it should be the responsibility of the display tier (`QTableView` or the delegate) to handle the display of new frames.

Does anyone know a clean (and preferably efficient) way to display animation in Qt views?

---

For those interested, here is the code of the delegate I developped (which does not work at the moment).

```
// Class that paints movie frames every time they change, using the painter
// and style options provided
class MoviePainter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

  public: // member functions
    MoviePainter( QMovie * movie, 
                  QPainter * painter, 
                  const QStyleOptionViewItem & option );

  public slots:
    void paint( ) const;

  private: // member variables
    QMovie               * movie_;
    QPainter             * painter_;
    QStyleOptionViewItem   option_;
};


MoviePainter::MoviePainter( QMovie * movie,
                            QPainter * painter,
                            const QStyleOptionViewItem & option )
  : movie_( movie ), painter_( painter ), option_( option )
{
    connect( movie, SIGNAL( frameChanged( int ) ),
             this,  SLOT( paint( ) ) );
}

void MoviePainter::paint( ) const
{
    const QPixmap & pixmap = movie_->currentPixmap();

    painter_->save();
    painter_->drawPixmap( option_.rect, pixmap );
    painter_->restore();
}

//-------------------------------------------------

//Custom delegate for handling animated decorations.
class MovieDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT

  public: // member functions
    MovieDelegate( QObject * parent = 0 );
    ~MovieDelegate( );

    void paint( QPainter * painter, 
                const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, 
                const QModelIndex & index ) const;

  private: // member functions
    QMovie * qVariantToPointerToQMovie( const QVariant & variant ) const;

  private: // member variables
    mutable std::map< QModelIndex, detail::MoviePainter * > map_;
};

MovieDelegate::MovieDelegate( QObject * parent )
  : QStyledItemDelegate( parent )
{
}

MovieDelegate::~MovieDelegate( )
{
    typedef  std::map< QModelIndex, detail::MoviePainter * > mapType;

          mapType::iterator it = map_.begin();
    const mapType::iterator end = map_.end();

    for ( ; it != end ; ++it )
    {
        delete it->second;
    }
}

void MovieDelegate::paint( QPainter * painter, 
                           const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, 
                           const QModelIndex & index ) const
{
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint( painter, option, index );

    const QVariant & data = index.data( Qt::DecorationRole );

    QMovie * movie = qVariantToPointerToQMovie( data );

    // Search index in map
    typedef std::map< QModelIndex, detail::MoviePainter * > mapType;

    mapType::iterator it = map_.find( index );

    // if the variant is not a movie
    if ( ! movie )
    {
        // remove index from the map (if needed)
        if ( it != map_.end() )
        {
            delete it->second;
            map_.erase( it );
        }

        return;
    }

    // create new painter for the given index (if needed)
    if ( it == map_.end() )
    {
        map_.insert( mapType::value_type( 
                index, new detail::MoviePainter( movie, painter, option ) ) );
    }
}

QMovie * MovieDelegate::qVariantToPointerToQMovie( const QVariant & variant ) const
{
    if ( ! variant.canConvert< QMovie * >() ) return NULL;

    return variant.value< QMovie * >();
}
```

Comment: I found something quite similar in [`QxtItemDelegate`](http://www.koders.com/cpp/fid5911A4434425C7038B6C507A5BF978C82A6294FD.aspx), an extension to `QtItemDelegate` which enable drawing progress bars (among other things). To do so, this delegate uses an approach quite similar to the one proposed in my question, but it stores views and indexes instead of painters; at each timeout of a timer, the delegate update all the views, preferably only the items that need update.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best solution is to use [QSvgRenderer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsvgrenderer.html) within delegate.

[image]

It's very easy to implement and unlike gif, SVG is lightweight and supports transparency.

```
    TableViewDelegate::TableViewDelegate(TableView* view, QObject* parent)
    : QStyledItemDelegate(parent), m_view(view)
{
    svg_renderer = new QSvgRenderer(QString{ ":/res/img/spinning_icon.svg" }, m_view);

    connect(svg_renderer, &QSvgRenderer::repaintNeeded,
        [this] {
        m_view->viewport()->update();
    });
}


void TableViewDelegate::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option,
    const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    QStyleOptionViewItem opt{ option };
    initStyleOption(&opt, index);

    if (index.column() == 0) {
        if (condition)
        {
            // transform bounds, otherwise fills the whole cell
            auto bounds = opt.rect;
            bounds.setWidth(28);
            bounds.moveTo(opt.rect.center().x() - bounds.width() / 2,
                opt.rect.center().y() - bounds.height() / 2);

            svg_renderer->render(painter, bounds);
        }
    }

    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, opt, index);
}
```

[Here's](https://loading.io/) a nice website where you can generate your own spinning icon and export in SVG.

Comment: Note that most (all?) animated SVGs from loading.io use the `<animate>` tag, which seems not to be supported by `QSvgRenderer`, while others are (e.g. `<animateColor>` [deprecated in SVG], `<animateTransform>`). Some supported SVGs are provided by Sam Herbert: https://samherbert.net/svg-loaders/

Answer (score 6):

For the record, I ended up using [`QAbstractItemView::setIndexWidget`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/main-snapshot/qabstractitemview.html#setIndexWidget) from inside the `paint` method of my delegate, to insert a `QLabel` displaying the `QMovie` inside the item (see code below).

This solution works quite nicely, and keep the display issues separated from the model. One drawback is that the display of a new frame in the label causes the entire item to be rendered again, resulting in almost continuous calls to the delegate's `paint` method...

To reduce the overhead inccured by these calls, I tried to minimize the work done for handling movies in the delegate by reusing the existing label if there is one. However, this results in weird behavior when resizing the windows: the animation gets shifted to the right, as if two labels were positioned side by side.

So well, here is a possible solution, feel free to comment on ways to improve it!

```
// Declaration

#ifndef MOVIEDELEGATE_HPP
#define MOVIEDELEGATE_HPP

#include <QtCore/QModelIndex>
#include <QtGui/QStyledItemDelegate>


class QAbstractItemView;
class QMovie;


class MovieDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT

  public: // member functions

    MovieDelegate( QAbstractItemView & view, QObject * parent = NULL );

    void paint( QPainter * painter, 
                const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, 
                const QModelIndex & index ) const;


  private: // member functions

    QMovie * qVariantToPointerToQMovie( const QVariant & variant ) const;


  private: // member variables

    mutable QAbstractItemView & view_;
};

#endif // MOVIEDELEGATE_HPP


// Definition

#include "movieDelegate.hpp"

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtGui/QAbstractItemView>
#include <QtGui/QLabel>
#include <QtGui/QMovie>


Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( QMovie * )


//---------------------------------------------------------
// Public member functions
//---------------------------------------------------------

MovieDelegate::MovieDelegate( QAbstractItemView & view, QObject * parent )
  : QStyledItemDelegate( parent ), view_( view )
{
}


void MovieDelegate::paint( QPainter * painter, 
                           const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, 
                           const QModelIndex & index ) const
{
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint( painter, option, index );

    const QVariant & data = index.data( Qt::DecorationRole );

    QMovie * movie = qVariantToPointerToQMovie( data );

    if ( ! movie )
    {
        view_.setIndexWidget( index, NULL );
    }
    else
    {
        QObject * indexWidget = view_.indexWidget( index );
        QLabel  * movieLabel  = qobject_cast< QLabel * >( indexWidget );

        if ( movieLabel )
        {
            // Reuse existing label

            if ( movieLabel->movie() != movie )
            {
                movieLabel->setMovie( movie );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Create new label;

            movieLabel = new QLabel;

            movieLabel->setMovie( movie );

            view_.setIndexWidget( index, movieLabel );
        }
    }
}


//---------------------------------------------------------
// Private member functions
//---------------------------------------------------------

QMovie * MovieDelegate::qVariantToPointerToQMovie( const QVariant & variant ) const
{
    if ( ! variant.canConvert< QMovie * >() ) return NULL;

    return variant.value< QMovie * >();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide full code, how did you write the delegate. I posted similar question for `QListView`and looking for solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812979/how-to-show-animated-icon-in-qlistview?noredirect=1#comment51562370_31812979

Comment: @zadane The full code of the delegate is already provided in my answer. You just need to make sure your `QListView` uses this delegate by calling `QAbstractItemView::setItemDelegate` or a similar function.

Comment: I create same class like you did but I can't instantiate the delegate `movieDelegate = new MovieDelegate( this );` gives error `C:\code\svn2\Sync\mainwindow.cpp:72: error: C2664: 'MovieDelegate::MovieDelegate(QAbstractItemView &,QObject *)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'MainWindow *const ' to 'QAbstractItemView &'` My containing view is MainWindow

Comment: @zadane The `MovieDelegate` constructor takes an additional parameter, you need to pass the view it will be assigned to (your `QListView`): `movieDelegate = new MovieDelegate(*ui.myListView, this)`, or something like that..

Comment: thanks now compiles but It doesn't produce animation. I am setting animating gif file as the icon and just one frame shows up, no animation. `new QStandardItem( QIcon( ":icons/Resources/connecting.gif"), "connecting);` do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Inside the delegate's `paint()` function, control goes into     if ( ! movie )
    {
        view_.setIndexWidget( index, NULL );
    } so it seems like movie is not running in the first place.

Comment: @zadane The `MovieDelegate` I wrote expects a `QMovie`, not a `QIcon`. You must make sure that your model returns a `QMovie` when asked for data with the role `Qt::DecorationRole`. You must also make sure the movie is started/stopped according to your requirements (if you want the animation to keep rolling, you can simply start it after creating it).

Comment: @zadane Here are some snippets from the code of my model. I created the movies in the constructor: `movies_.push_back(new QMovie(":/images/ajax-loader.gif")),`. Then in the `data` function, I returned the appropriate movie: `case Qt::DecorationRole: return QVariant::fromValue(movies_[idx]);`. For this to work, you must register `QMovie` to the Qt meta-type system: `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QMovie *)`.

Comment: did you derived your own model class from QStandardItemModel? I haven't used model at that level or `data` function but that something I am looking into it now.

Answer (score 4):

In my application, I have a typical spinning circle icon to indicate a waiting/processing state for some of the cells in a table. However I ended up using an approach, which is different from the one suggested in the currently accepted answer, mine is in my view simpler and somewhat more performant (UPDATE: I wrote this when a different answer was set as accepted - the one suggesting using `QAbstractItemView::setIndexWidget`). Using widgets seems as an overkill which will destroy the performance if there are too many of them. All the functionality in my solution is only implemented in my model layer (descendant of `QAbstractItemModel`) class. I do not need to make any changes in the view nor the delegate. I am however only animating one GIF and all animations are synchronized. This is the current limitation of my simple approach.

The model class which is used to implement this behavior needs to have the following:

- the vector of `QImage`s - I use `QImageReader`, which allows me read all animation frames, I store them into a `QVector<QImage>`
- a `QTimer` ticking with the periodicity of the animated GIF - the time period is obtained using `QImageReader::nextImageDelay()`.
- the index (int) of the current frame (I suppose the frame is the same for all animated cells - they are synchronized; if you want unsynchronized then you can use an integer offset for each of them)
- some knowledge of which cells should be animated and ability to translate the cell to `QModelIndex` (this is up to your custom code to implement this, depend on your specific needs)
- override `QAbstractItemModel::data()` part of your model to respond to `Qt::DecorationRole` for any animated cell (`QModelIndex`) and return the current frame as a `QImage`
- a slot which is triggered by the `QTimer::timeout` signal

The key part is the slot which reacts to the timer. It must do this:

1. Increase the current frame, e.g. `m_currentFrame = (m_currentFrame + 1) % m_frameImages.size();`
2. Get the list of indices (e.g. `QModelIndexList getAnimatedIndices();`) of the cells which have to be animated. This code of `getAnimatedIndices()` is up to you to develop - use brute force querying all cells in your model or some clever optimization...
3. emit `dataChanged()` signal for each animated cell, e.g. `for (const QModelIndex &idx : getAnimatedIndices()) emit dataChanged(idx, idx, {Qt::DecorationRole});`

Thats all. I estimate that depending on the complexity of your functions for determining which indices are animated, the whole implementation can have something like 15 to 25 lines, without need to alter the view nor delegate, just the model.

Comment: Can you provide a working example of this approach? I've been looking around and it's the one that convinces me the most (the only part I am not convinced with is the fact that you cannot use animated svg's - which are great on multiple screen configurations and light)

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use QMovie with GIF.
I also tried using SVG (it's lightweight and offers support for transparency), but both QMovie and QImageReader don't seem to support animated SVG.

```
Model::Model(QObject* parent) : QFileSystemModel(parent)
{
    movie = new QMovie{ ":/resources/img/loading.gif" };
    movie->setCacheMode(QMovie::CacheAll);
    movie->start();

    connect(movie, &QMovie::frameChanged,
    [this] {
        dataChanged(index(0, 0), index(rowCount(), 0),
            QVector<int>{QFileSystemModel::FileIconRole});
    });
}

QVariant Model::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const
{
    case QFileSystemModel::FileIconRole:
    {
        if (index.column() == 0) {
            auto const path = QString{ index.data(QFileSystemModel::FilePathRole).toString() };

            if (path.isBeingLoaded()){
                return movie->currentImage();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: very decent solution. I have been searching for a long to find this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a QMovie-based solution to animate individual items in a QListView/QTableView, when they are visible (the use case was animated gifs in messages, in a chat program). The solution is similar to the QSvgRenderer solution in another answer, but it uses QMovie and it adds a "map" of currently visible indexes with a QMovie (each). See commits https://github.com/KDE/ruqola/commit/49015e2aac118fd97b7327a55c19f2e97f37b1c9 and https://github.com/KDE/ruqola/commit/2b358fb0471f795289f9dc13c256800d73accae4.